# PostgreSQL naming conventions

Tags: postgresql, naming-convention

Maybe double post but I could not find any answer here.

I saw couple of posts how to name my tables and I understood that (semi-officially) it should contain lower cases, should be underscored and singular (f.e. my_table)

My question arose when I had to do the following.
I have an app where I have user, platform and user_info, where platform is what the user is working on (f.e. MAC, PC, LINUX). If I need to create junction table between user and platform, how do I name it in order the next person browsing the schema to understand that user and platform have a junction table named user_platform, but to not be confused when he sees the table user_info?

BR

Comment: Choose one naming convention and **stick to it**! Use a search engine. Personally, I go with UPPER CASE for SQL and lower for other variables `SELECT my_field FROM my_table;` but that's me. See what suits you. p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, but I cannot understand the answer. I am having difficulties naming junction tables and tables consisting of two nouns (user_info, order_details and so on)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case the reasoning behind lower-case names wasn't clear, here's why: Postgres **automatically and invisibly** folds names down. So, all of these names are the same:

```
user_platform

USER_PLATFORM

UsEr_PlAtFoRm
```

They're all user_platform internally. Unless you put them in double-quotes:

"UserPlatform" is "UserPlatform". But to use this field or table, you would then need to put the name in double quotes *everywhere* you use it. It's a total pain. So, it's pretty standard to see names like

```
user_platform
```

With that said, as long as you don't use the double-quotes, you can write the name

```
User_Platform
```

if you find it easier to read.

As far as the naming convention goes, yes, pick one, **stick to it** and document your rules. You get 64 characters to work with (by default), which I haven't found to be an issue, except sometimes for index names.

For linking tables, whatever you like is fine. Linking users and platforms?

```
user_platform

user_link_platform
```

whatever you prefer.

As far as the singular vs. plural argument, it's a matter of taste. Some people care. A lot. The gutters run red with the blood of the unrighteous! I say do whatever you like. I'm of the make-table-names-singular school, but mostly because it's a habit that I picked up long ago.

Ah, one thing about the double-quotes...I do use them. We ship Postgres data to a visualization/analytics program called Domo. For that, it's nicer to have column (attribute) names in MixedCase. For that, I create views with "MixedCase" column aliases so that the data exports with a "MixedCase" name. This is a slightly exotic scenario, but maybe you'll run into something similar one day. Normally, I'd change the tables client-side, but the views were the easier solution.

Bonus tip! If you haven't discovered it already, Postgres text fields are case-sensitive. If you don't like that, you can:

- Write your queries to deal with the data case-blindly. Every. Single. Query.
- Use the standard citext extension. (Case Insensitive Text.)
- Wait for PG12 to ship with case-insensitive collations. (Haven't tried it out yet.)

Forgot to mention...Postgres has unusually good support for commenting on system elements, including tables:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html

Someone has to look for and read your comments, of course, but it's another place that you can provide context. Even if that context is nothing but a link to a wiki you maintain, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I will stick with link in between like user_link_platform. Makes more sense if you start reading. Or user_platform_xref.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of using a naming convention of (noun) _ n _ (noun) for link tables.
as in user_n_platform.
Though I wish dash was allowed. 
Then user-platform could link two tables 
but user_platform would be its own table.